Transaction Management Across Microservices with Rollback Mechanism using Kafka
I am currently developing a microservices architecture consisting of two services, and I'm facing a challenge related to transaction management and error handling.

Microservice A: This service is responsible for receiving data, saving it to a PostgreSQL database using Entity Framework Core, and publishing relevant events to Microservice B via Kafka using MassTransit.
  await _context.DeliveryDocuments.AddRangeAsync(deliveryDocuments, cancellationToken);

  await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

  await _publisher.Publish(new DeliveryRequestSavedEvent(deliveryRequest, EventType.Create), cancellationToken);


Microservice B: This service consumes the messages published by Microservice A and performs certain business logic based on the received data. However, there are scenarios where Microservice B can fail during processing, potentially throwing exceptions.
   public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DeliveryRequestFromSiteBusMessage> context)    
   throw new Exception();



Given this architecture, I want to ensure that if Microservice B encounters an error, any associated changes made by Microservice A (i.e., saving data to the database) are not committed. Essentially, I am looking to implement a rollback mechanism to maintain data consistency across the services.
In my service A the logic is very simple. It's very unlikely that data will fail during saving to db, otherwise on service B its alloat of risk that something goes wrong, alloat of complex logic so i need to provide some mechanism that will commit transaction on microservice 1 after the data is consumed and handled on service B, the delay doesn`t matter, about cleanup i think its not possiable because im not just creating new objects, im also existing once, and i dont want to hold state of previous objects, so i dont think cleanup is a good idea.
I would like to know the best approaches, tools, and design patterns to effectively manage transactions across these microservices. Specifically:

What are the recommended patterns for ensuring data consistency, such as the Outbox Pattern or Sagas? Which one of them is suitable in my case?
How can I implement compensating transactions to roll back changes in Microservice A if Microservice B fails?
I read about transaction outbox pattern on masstransit
https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/transactional-outbox
but i understand it's not working with kafka, so i guess i left with saga?

Any insights or examples of how to achieve this type of rollback mechanism in a microservices environment would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

"What are the recommended patterns for ensuring data consistency, such as the Outbox Pattern or Sagas?" - the recommended patterns are Outbox or Saga, so do you really have a question at point #1 (except "give me a list of more patterns" - which is not well received by our community)?

And to #2: this is quite broad from this 100K feet view. Such rollbacks can depend on the structure of the data, the nature of the business logic, and how urgent such a rollback has to be processes. For example. is it possible to include a processing state into the data? Is it possible to delete not sucessfully processed data by a cleanup process with some delay? Or does B have to send an event back to A that a request was not fulfilled  sucessfully, so A needs to rollback these things immediately? Try to be more specific about your case, otherwise we could only write a "catch all" answer.

Clarifications down here in comments don't improve your question (especially when they don'r reveal any specifics). I recommend to use the "edit" button and include a specific example as well as some context into the question text. Don't forget, though the case might be clear for you, we cannot read your mind.

“im also existing once” huh?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If all work in A is undone when B throws an exception, then these microservices are obviously not independent.
It sounds like just two stages of a queue. A receives data provisionally for processing. B then performs the processing, and either commits the data permanently or scraps it completely.
A standard requirement for a microservice is that any one of the set works when any other is offline and unavailable, and recovers spontaneously when connections resume.
And the standard size of a "microservice" is that a single one has a full-time team dedicated to looking after it. You appear to be looking after two related microservices single-handedly.
For heaven's sake just throw out all the junk layers and frameworks and clutter you mention, and write the whole thing in one Postgres database engine using a transaction.
This approach will almost certainly differ from your existing one by being simple and by working correctly.

The problem is if it would so simple, i wouldnot do it from the start, the service B is located in another department and maintained by another team, also we have policies in company about using frameworks etc., so i have no another way than implement some rolleback mechanism for this services

Also, i have only db postgres, and is what service A is using, service B have db of its own but it have access to the db of service A

@OlegPro, if you don't look after the B microservice, and can't hand all this work over to team B, then surely you'd just have A either respond to a callback from B when an exception occurs (by deleting/reversing the work at A), or have A query B for the result of the processing of all pending cases? (1/2)

I mean there's likely to be subtle flaws and inefficiencies as there always is when there is gratuitous technical complexity created, but if your firm isn't interested in making the bigger picture simple and rationalised, and you have no control, then I wouldn't worry too much. (2/2)
